# D7 Garland color style.css changes

Tags: theming

I want to make changes to the Garland theme. But it seems the style.css file is generated. I tried to change style.css and put my css about "do not touch" clause ( under CSS Support ). It's not working. Style.css file in the theme folder is not imported on the fly? Can anyone help me out?

Comment: check garland.info file for  - `stylesheets[all][] = style.css`

Comment: You can also use css_inject module. It's will be more correct, becuse you don`t need to modify theme files, and it will be frendly for update.

Comment: css injector got the job done. @neok: can you tell me more from there? I saw this line.